# What causes it for a phosphorescence material to give light for a relative long time?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, particle-physics

When a phosphorescence material is shined by a flashlight for say 1 minute it will start to glow right away and can last for let say an hour or so. That implies that some of the excited atoms are immediately falling back to their ground state while other seems to wait for that an hour or so. And it looks that the object is pretty equal shining. How can this occur?

Is this similar to a kind of half-life in case of decay of atoms?

Comment: The transitions responsible for phosphoresence are "forbidden" transitions. Typically they connect an excited triplet state (with unpaired electrons) to a singlet state (paired electrons). Since optical transitions cannot change the spin of the electron, these transition requires a external perturbation (collission for example) in order to occur which may take much longer than the "allowed" transititions. You can indeed describe this with an exponential decay like in radioactive atoms.

Comment: @Paul Do I understand you right that the photons released by such an atom can only be emitted when it is hit by another photon of the material,  a bit like in a laser occurs?

Comment: There will always be some spin-orbit coupling that allows spin-forbidden transitions.

Comment: @Marijn; Pieter is right that other processes such as spin-orbit coupling may induce forbidden transitions as well, the main point is that forbidden transitions become allowed by slow processes that arise from neglected contributions to the Hamiltonian.